# WebAdministration powershell module not found on windows server data center

Tags: windows, powershell

In Windows Server 2008 Datacenter, I could not find the PowerShell `webadministration` module. I tried `Get-PSSnapin` and `Get-Module -ListAvailable`, neither of which showed `webadministration`

And I don't see the `webadministration` module under the directory `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` !!

Do I need to install or enable something to have `webadministration` on Datacenter ?

Answer (score 10):

You need to have web server role (IIS) installed. WebAdministration is a module. So, use `Get-Module -ListAvailable`

Also, looks like these cmdlets are available only on Windows Server 2008 R2 or with IIS 7.5. So, if you have IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008, these cmdlets will be available.

Comment: Hi Ravi, web server role is installed , I tried Get-Module -ListAvailable it did not show WebAdministration also as mentioned earlier under the module directory WebAdministration module is not there!

Comment: Interesting. So, you are using Windows Server 2008 and not R2. Right? What do you see when you do `Get-PSSnapin -Registered`?

Comment: info related Microsoft.Powershell.Sharepoint, SqlserverCmdletSnapin100, Sqlserverprovidersnapin100  snapins thats all

Comment: Hmm, I have a feeling that this module is available only on R2. I don't have a WIndows 2008 system to verify this at the moment.

Comment: Check this link: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/29/installing-iis-7-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2/ I could not find any MS official doc on this.

Answer (score 6):

You can [install the snapin](http://www.iis.net/download/powershell). You can then use [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924217/powershell-load-webadministration-in-ps1-script-on-both-iis-7-and-iis-7-5/4325963#4325963) to load it.

Comment: Whether this installation can be redistributed along with our software?

Answer (score 2):

For automation with **Windows Server 2008**, We use **[WebPiCmd](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-v4-command-line-webpicmdexe-rtw-release)** to push [**IISPowershellSnapin**](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/powershell), then run `Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration` to support IIS powershell integration. The IIS Administration Module is already present in **Windows Server 2012** by default.

#### Powershell - Support IIS Administration for Server 2008

```cs
.\WebpiCmd.exe /Install /Products:IISPowershellSnapin /AcceptEula /ForceReboot
Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration
Get-Website
```