# Getting error related to WinRm and WebAdministration not installed

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to get the sites being hosted in multiple remote servers using the below script:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$servers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\serv.txt
foreach($server in $servers)
{
    Invoke-Command  -ComputerName $servers { Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-ChildItem -path IIS:\Sites | Format-Table} | Out-File "C:\Users

    \Administrator\Desktop\detail.txt"
}
```

But I am getting error. Detail.txt has been created. But the file is empty. Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebAdministration powershell module not found on windows server data center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963647/webadministration-powershell-module-not-found-on-windows-server-data-center)

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow!  Please share the error details.

Comment: when i executed above script i got the below error:
[server01] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests.

I have checked the WinRm service and is installed and running fine. Latter i tried below script:

Comment: Import-Module WebAdministration
$servers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\serv.txt
Function Load-WebAdmin {
  $webAdminModule = get-module -ListAvailable | ? { $_.Name -eq "webadministration" }
  If ($webAdminModule -ne $null) {
    import-module WebAdministration
  }else{
    Add-pssnapin WebAdministration
   }
}
foreach($server in $servers)
{
Invoke-Command  -ComputerName $server {Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-Website} | Out-File "C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\detail.txt"
}
No errors on execution, but detail.txt file is empty.